# sed, using line number

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace some lines, but somehow I would like to add line number to the end of replaced line.

s/display/echo print {LINENUMBER}/

```
input file:
lorem ipsum
display

output:
lorem ipsum
echo print 2
```

Can I do this with sed ?

Thanks in advance.

Cs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sed = function to write the line number on a line by itself and sed d function to delete the matching pattern. So :

```
sed '/^display$/{=
d
}' [input file]
```

will output :

```
lorem ipsum
2
```

Assuming you don't have numbers on a line by themselves in the original file you can chain a second sed command to add the ‘echo print’ for those lines, something like :

```
sed  's/^(\d+)$/echo print \1/'
```

although the exact syntax may change depending on your system (\d not always being available and so on...)

`sed` is probably not the simplest tool to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I would do that with `awk`:

```
awk '{if($0=="display") {print "echo print",NR} else print $0}' < file
```

Comment: +1, although I would write it a little less C-like: `awk '/display/ {print "echo print", NR; next} 1' file`

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe '$_ = "echo print $.\n" if /display/' input
```